# PostgreSQL: Order by Index

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I've a table with 75 entries. Some have the type attraction, some have the type "random restaurant". I've created an ordered list of the "random restaurants" with the following code:

```
SELECT name 
FROM punkte AS p, 
     linien AS l 
WHERE l.route = 'Parade route' 
  AND p.typ = 'Random restaurant' 
ORDER BY ST_Distance(l.wkb_geometry, p.wkb_geometry) ASC
```

My Output looks like this (it's a subset of my bigger table):

[image: output table]

Similar to this order by distance I want to rate my restaurants. A new column should be created with a value from 1 to 6 depending on their sorting.

Do you know a way to do this?

Solution (thanks to Adrian):

```
SELECT 
    row_number() over(ORDER BY ST_Distance(l.wkb_geometry, p.wkb_geometry) ASC),
    name 
FROM 
    punkte AS p, 
    linien AS l 
WHERE 
    l.route = 'Parade route' 
    AND p.typ = 'Random restaurant'
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a reasonable thing to want.  The indices don't mean anything to SQL.  Can't you assign those numbers in whatever language you're using to pull the query?

Comment: 1) Per [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) do not use images. Copy and paste the data as text into your question. 2) Add new column where? 3) What do you mean temporary indexes? 4) What does  *How can I get these indices of my order by query?* mean?  They either already exist on the table or they don't. 4) What is the problem you are trying to solve? **ADD ANSWERS as update to question**.

Comment: Hey Tim, I've updated the post. The temporary indices are based on the distance. They'll give my restaurant a rating. My Question is similar to your idea, I want to assign these numbers to a new column, but I'll get these numbers only by the query. But I don't know how to access these numbers.

Comment: 1) If by temporary index you mean the 1..6 values then those are an artifact of your client and are not part of the data returned by the query. 2) If you want them in the output then `SELECT row_number() over(),  name  ....`.

Comment: Instead of updating the question with the solution, put the solution in as an answer so that others can immediately identify the post as having an answer.